# How to run SML REPL in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, sml

I am trying to use SML/NJ in Visual Studio Code editor but can't figure out how to run SML REPL in Visual Studio Code. I have installed SML extension in Visual Studio Code but no documentation is available. How to configure SML in Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 2):

Have you installed latest SML/NJ version ? Download from here https://www.smlnj.org/dist/working/index.html

Install it.

Now open VSCode, go to menu Terminal > New terminal.
In terminal type `sml` and confirm command. It will enter the SML/NJ REPL mode.

Answer (score 1):

On linux, you can open a bash terminal with Ctrl-j and use the sml command (if you have it installed) to get an integrated REPL.

Answer (score 0):

To run REPL one can set-up a task for VSCode like this:

```
{
        "label": "SML REPL",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "sml ${file}",
}
```

this task will run current file with REPL.

It is also possible to use problem matcher and then issues (at least with syntax) will be highlighted directly in editor.